# moving database from old disk to new disk

Tags: mysql

I need to move a database from an old disk which is no longer bootable to a new bootable disk. I have been able to mount the old disk. Now I need to move the database from there to a new disk. Can this be done? Where do I start and what do I need to move?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a new database with the same name on the new system, shut down the service, replace the new (empty) files for your database with the old ones and finally start the service again. See http://www.kimvette.net/linux/recover_and_mount_mysql_database_files_after_recovery for more info.

Comment: Thank you. I've printed the information out and will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have logged in as `root`

1. Shut down MySQL server (myqsladmin shutdown)
2. Edit /etc/my.cnf and set the data-dir configuration option to the new location of your MySQL data directory.
3. Move your entire data directory to the new location, ie: mv /var/lib/mysql/* /mnt/mysql/
4. Ensure permissions are correct, chown -R mysql:mysql /mnt/mysql
5. Start MySQL as usual.

Comment: +1 but I'd use `cp` instead of `mv` just in case something goes wrong in the process. It's basically copying anyway when you `mv` from one filesystem to the other.